# Python: Bad File Descriptor when reusing a socket

Tags: python, sockets

I have a socket that I use and then closed it. I f I tried to re use it, I get the following error:

```
  File "myCode.py", line 83, 
    votingSocket.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_VOTING_PORT))
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  File "..\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Here is my code:

```
votingSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def VotingSessionOnOff():
    global votingSocket
    if (on)
        if votingSocket is None:
            votingSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        votingSocket.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_VOTING_PORT))
        votingSocket.listen(NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS) 

        print 'Server opened voting socket!'
    else:
        votingSocket.close()
```

When I call the `VotingSessionOnOff()` the first time it runs just good, calling it a further time gives the previous error.

Comment: Is `votingSocket` still opened or not `None`?

Comment: it should be closed after the 1st call, I am not sure if it is set t None or not

Comment: You need to provide a calling sequence that produces the error, including code that sets/clears `on` between calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python socket (Socket Error Bad File Descriptor)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382899/python-socket-socket-error-bad-file-descriptor)

Comment: See also [How to use socket in Python as a context manager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772465/how-to-use-socket-in-python-as-a-context-manager)