# I'm converting ints to chars and trying to send them from a C client to a Python server on another computer. Getting 'send: Bad address'

Tags: sockets, utf-8, char

On one computer with the client (written in C) I get the error `send: Bad address` when I try to send chars to another computer with a server written in Python. But the address is NOT bad.
If instead of chars I just send a written string, `"A string written like this"` I can send it just fine to the server and see it print with no problems. So, I don't think there is really a problem with an address.

I have also tried converting the int to a string. I get error when compiling `cannot convert string to char`. I have tried variations and I can only compile with the client written as it is below.

The client (in C)

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ADDR "192.168.0.112"
#define PORT "12003"

void sendall(int socket, char *bytes, int length)
{
    int n = 0, total = 0;
    while (total < length) {
        n = send(socket, bytes + total, total-length, 0);
        if (n == -1) {
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }
        total += n;
    }
}

void thesock(char *ADDRf, char *PORTf, char *RAZZstr)
{
    struct addrinfo hints = {0}, *addr = NULL;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    int status = getaddrinfo(ADDRf, PORTf, &hints, &addr);
    if (status != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error message";
        exit(1);
    }
    
    int sock = -1;
    struct addrinfo *p = NULL;
    for (p = addr; p != NULL; p = addr->ai_next) {
        sock = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
        if (sock == -1) {
                continue;
        }
        if (connect(sock, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) != -1) {
                break;
        }
        close(sock);
    }
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "connect(), socket()\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sendall(sock, RAZZstr, 12);
    close(sock);
}

int main()
{
    int someInt = 321;
    char strss[12];
    sprintf(strss, "%d", someInt);  
    
    thesock(ADDR, PORT, strss);

    return 0;
}
```

This last part of the code above is where the chars, or string is entered. It's this part of the code where you can replace `strss` in `thesock` with a string written in the `strss` position `"just like this"` and it will send to the server on the other computer written in Python. Though, when compiling I do get warnings `ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’`.

The server (In Python)

```
import os
import sys
import socket

s=socket.socket()

host='192.168.0.112'
port=12003

s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(11)

while True:
    c, addr=s.accept()
    content=c.recv(29).decode('utf-8')

    print(content)
```

This server decodes `utf-8`. I don't know if I have the option for a different 'decode' here. I don't think Python has 'chars'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: this is unrelated to "address" in terms of IP address but it is about invalid access to a local memory access.

```
int n = 0, total = 0;
while (total < length) {
    n = send(socket, bytes + total, total-length, 0);
```

`total - length` is a negative number, i.e. `0-12 = -12` in your case. The third argument of `send` is of type `size_t`, i.e. an unsigned integer. The negative number (-12) thus gets cast into an unsigned integer, resulting in a huge unsigned integer.

This causes `send` to access memory far outside the allocated memory for `bytes`, hence EFAULT "Bad address".

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this. Coming from Python. It's confusing. I've seen there are some times memory is specified with a `variable[12]`. Sometimes memory is explicitly programmed, and sometimes it's not. What I'm getting at is, is there a name for this? I don't know what this is called or how to get a grasp of it. I mean, I could just treat the whole things as a black box. But this hung me up for more than a few hours.

Comment: @user7914198: *" ... is there a name for this?"* - I I'm not sure what you mean, maybe [pointer arithmetic](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm)?

Comment: I don't know what I mean either. I've never encountered a program dealing with memory addresses till now. I don't know where to begin to learn more about it.

Comment: @user7914198: C is a low level language: Properly caring about memory is essential part of this, there is no boundary checking, automatic garbage collection or something like this in the language. Since it is such an essential part when writing C programs any good book about C will cover this topic. Don't expect C to learn just by reading a few tutorials - it is way more complex than that.